# Cannot connect to Localstack SQS from Javascript v3 Client

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

When creating a [Localstack](https://docs.localstack.cloud/user-guide/aws/sqs/) instance for testing: I can create a queue and everything seems to work fine via the AWS CLI. I can see it exists and send/receive messages.

However when I try use the [Javascript v3 Client](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/client/sqs/) no matter what I do I can't seem to get it to connect.

In the v3 SDK, you specify the Queue URL in the request as so:

```
      const command = new SendMessageCommand({
      QueueUrl: 'http://localhost:4566/000000000000/requestQueue',
      MessageAttributes: {
        Source: {
          DataType: 'String',
          StringValue: 'Agent X',
        },
      },
      MessageBody: JSON.stringify({ event }),
    });

    try {
      const response = await this.sqsClient.send(command);
```

However it will always say something like "Error: InvalidAddress: The address https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ is not valid for this endpoint". I have tried so many variations of this I am truly at my wits end. Am I just missing something obvious?

I am using a variation of [this sample](https://github.com/localstack/localstack-demo) to bootstrap the queue and I am quite confident the queue both exists and works.

Answer (score 1):

I eventually figured this out after playing for many hours. You need to specify an endpoint in the SQS Constructor. If anybody runs into the same issue:

```
 constructor() {
    const url: URL = new URL('http://localhost:4566'); //<-- this is the fixer
    const endpoint: EndpointV2 = {
      url: url,
    };
    this.sqsClient = new SQSClient({ region: 'us-east-1', endpoint: endpoint }); 
  }
```